# Integrating Google Analytics Into Google Doc

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to pull data from a google analytics and put it into a google doc spreadsheet.  The main issues seems to be I can't enter my GA Key.  All the tutorials have said to enter it in a text box that should be at the end of the `resources -> use` Google API form.  But I see no textbox there, only a message that I have to enable the APIs in the API console to use them.

I've confirmed that I do have Google Analytics enabled in the API console.

The error messages I get are either `User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.` or `Analytics not defined` if I try to type my API key in the text box that says 'Analytics' (which leads me to believe that's defining the variable image).

Comment: Are you following this https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned that.  I was following that article, I've also watched http://analytics.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/automate-google-analytics-reporting.html and no dice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the script is running as "you" you do not need to enter the GA id - it will use the permissions for the account that you were logged in with while creating and authorising that script. That account needs admin permissions for the Google Analytics account you intend to query.

The box that you thought is for the API key holds the name for the analytics object in the script. If you change that you'd need to change all instances of "Analytics" in the script to the name you entered.

For example there is a line in the script that goes:

```
var accounts = Analytics.Management.Accounts.list();
```

This will list all accounts connected to the user who authorised that script. You see that the first part is "Analytics" (the global Analytics object in the script), if you enter something in the resources->Google APIs tab you'd need to change that as well - that's why you get an error message "Analytics is not defined" when you change that value.

Hard to tell about your actual problem, probably you are just missing admin permissions in analytics.